# Keyboard does not work after PC wakes from sleep

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, sleep

I am running a Windows 7 desktop. Recently, when I wake up my computer, the mouse works, but the keyboard does not. If I need the keyboard, I have to restart the machine. Why does this happen, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Is this a USB keyboard or a PS/2 keyboard?  PS/2 keyboards sometimes aren't as resilient to power state changes.  At other times, the keyboard's internal controller may be having problems.  Do you have a keyboard you can swap with to see if the problem stays with the keyboard or the computer?

Comment: It's a usb keyboard. I'll look for a spare just to see what happens.

Comment: If you can't swap the keyboard right away, it might be worth swapping to another USB port (preferably one on a different controller) or removing other USB devices.  Sometimes another peripheral will interfere, so let's say your USB Whatzit that you bought off ebay isn't quite right, it could cause other USB devices to fail instead of itself.  Another problem is if too many high-drain devices are on the same controller. The keyboard might be requesting power and getting rejected.  Unplugging other devices may improve the keyboard.  I have seen a fair number of USB keyboards just simply fail.

Comment: I only have the keyboard, the mouse and a printer. I'll see what happens without the printer.

Comment: Same issue here - 2 keyboards connected, one via wired USB, one via Logitech Unify receiver. Both keyboards sometimes stop working but mouse input (from the same logitech receiver) is still possible. Drives me nuts. Could you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

This may be an issue with how Windows 7 disabled USB devices when it suspends. Try the following:

Control Panel -> Hardware & Sound -> Power Options -> Change Plan Settings (of current selected plan) -> Change Advanced Power Settings -> USB Selective Suspend Setting -> Disable (both)

Control Panel -> Hardware & Sound -> Power Options -> Change Plan Settings (of current selected plan) -> Change Advanced Power Settings -> PCI-Express -> Link State Power Management -> Disable (both)

Comment: I disabled both. Even though I can still use the keyboard to wake it up, the keyboard still won't work once the computer wakes up. The mouse is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Same thing happens to me ... but only once in a while. The problem then is that my password needs to be entered on waking from sleep, and that's hard to do when the keyboard doesn't work.

What works for me every time is to click on the "Handicapped" icon in the lower left of the screen. One of the options lets us use the mouse to select letters and numbers. Like typing on a mobile phone. I forget what it's called, but it won't be hard to find.

Once I enter my password and get logged in, the keyboard then works normally.

Answer (score 0):

Try unplugging and replugging the keyboard USB connection.  This always works for me, however I have found that occasionally the keyboard acts funky, typing numbers instead of letters, so PC rebooting is required.

Answer (score 0):

Symptoms:
Windows. Built-in ps/2 keyboard does not work after waking laptop from sleep mode. It shows up fine in device manager. But, if you return the laptop to sleep mode again, then the keyboard works fine. Or reload.
linux. On linux, everything is exactly the same, only the touchpad does not work after sleep mode.

SOLUTION THAT HELPED ME:

1. Restored bios settings to default.
2. I downloaded the bios.exe installer from the official website of the manufacturer of exactly the same version as I have and installed it (updated from version 4.4.0 to exactly the same 4.4.0).
3. Rebooted and everything worked!